# XSLT Optimizing xsl:choose and str:tokenize

Tags: xslt, optimization

I have been researching and haven't been able to find anything related to optimizing XSLT. Below is the snippet that I am working on and wanted to see if anything can be done to help with the xslt transformation.

```
<xsl:template match="a:OBR/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test ="name() = 'OBR-10' and string-length(.) = 0">
        <OBR-10>USER</OBR-10>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test ="name() = 'OBR-18'">
        <OBR-18>
          <xsl:value-of select ="//a:PV1/a:PV1-44"/>
        </OBR-18>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test ="name() = 'OBR-19'">
        <OBR-19>
            <xsl:if test = "string-length(str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5]) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select ="str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5]"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </OBR-19>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test ="name() = 'OBR-33'">
        <OBR-33>
          <xsl:value-of select ="translate(../parent::a:ORC[1]/a:ORC-4,'^','~')"/>
        </OBR-33>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='NTE'">
        <NTE>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </NTE>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='DG1'"/>
        <!--<DG1>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </DG1>
      </xsl:when>-->
      <xsl:when test="name()='OBX'">
        <OBX>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </OBX>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write code like

```
<xsl:template match="a:OBR/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test ="name() = 'OBR-10' and string-length(.) = 0">
        <OBR-10>USER</OBR-10>
      </xsl:when>
```

as

```
<xsl:template match="a:OBR/OBR-10[string-length() = 0]">
  <xsl:copy>USER</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or perhaps

```
<xsl:template match="a:OBR/OBR-10[. = '']">
  <xsl:copy>USER</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

that is, to write templates that match each element by its name and if needed a predicate/condition instead of that odd approach to match on `*` and then test the name. I don't see that necessarily as an optimization (you would have to measure with a particular implementation) but as a clear and modular coding style.

The

```
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
```

would then be code as

```
<xsl:template match="a:OBR/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

or probably already covered by an identity transformation template set up as the starting point to initiate and keep up the processing.

You would have to show the namespaces in the input document and the XSLT to allow a precise suggestion in terms of namespaces (could be that you want/need `xsl:template match="a:OBR/a:OBR-10[string-length() = 0]"`).

Comment: Thanks Martin how would I measure the two different options?

Comment: That depends on the XSLT processor and the host environment you use, you would need to check whether your XSLT processor has some option to directly output performance related data like processing time and memory consumption or you would need to turn to the host language (e.g. Java, C, C#, ...) you use to run the XSLT and write some code to time the XSLT transformation, perhaps together with OS specific tools. In any case, I would only bother doing that if you encounter some problems running the XSLT.

Comment: Sounds good would you change anything with this code
        <OBR-19>
            <xsl:if test = "string-length(str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5]) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select ="str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5]"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </OBR-19>
      </xsl:when>

Comment: Well, you have at least two options, one would be for clarity to use a variable `<xsl:variable name="token5" select="str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5]"/>` and then e.g. `<xsl:if test="$token5[string-length() > 0"><xsl:value-of select="$token5"/></xsl:if>`, on the other hand you could simply put the expression with a predicate into a single `value-of` with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5][normalize-space()]"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="str:tokenize(../a:OBR-18,'^')[5][string-length() > 0]"/>`.